# Why is my postgreSQL query not finding the correct object from my table?

Tags: postgresql

I'm getting stuff like == is not a symbol and command not found. What is the correct way to select a user by email?
This is my table schema:

```
-- Your database schema goes here --

-- USERS TABLE --
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;
CREATE TABLE users(userAccount jsonb);

-- SECRETS TABLE --
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS secrets;
CREATE TABLE secrets(secrets jsonb);
```

This is my populated table:

```
-- USERS TABLE POPULATION --
DELETE FROM users;
INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{"name":"Jack Cooper","password":"banana","email":"jc@gmail.com","role":"admin"}');
INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{"name":"Emmanuel Pena", "password":"potato", "email":"ep@gmail.com", "role": "admin"}');
```

The queries I have tried are:

```
SELECT userAccount FROM users WHERE userAccount->'email' ~* $1
SELECT userAccount FROM users WHERE userAccount->'email' LIKE $1
SELECT userAccount FROM users WHERE userAccount->'email' = $1
SELECT userAccount FROM users WHERE userAccount->'email' == $1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using json with single arrow, while filtering you want to use text as `json compared to string` is invalid in any SQL statement so use below syntax.

```
SELECT userAccount->'email' FROM users where userAccount->>'email'like'%@gmail.com';
```

> Reference for the same:
> https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-json/

How it works:

PostgreSQL provides two native operators -> and ->> to help you query JSON data.

```
The operator -> returns JSON object field by key.
The operator ->> returns JSON object field by text.
```

Comment: You can approve the answer if you find it helpful. Thanks